# Standalone ROS apps on macos

Tags: ros, roslaunch, rosrun, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All
is there an easy way I can convert a given roslaunch into a standalone Mac .app?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12256/standalone-ros-apps-on-macos/) by [Yogi](https://answers.ros.org/users/105/yogi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 411 on 2011-12-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's no generic way.

This is something that the OS X SIG has discussed; it's in the long-term plan. What it isn't is particularly near-term; OS X support is improving rapidly, but isn't to a point where just boxing things up makes sense.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2